# How to subtract R dataframe columns based on information in other dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'd like to add new columns to but where the calculation is dependant on values in another dataframe which holds instructions.

I have created a reproducible example below (although in reality there are quite a few more columns),

input dataframes:

```
base <- data.frame("A"=c("orange","apple","banana"),
                   "B"=c(5,3,6),
                   "C"=c(7,12,4),
                   "D"=c(5,2,7),
                   "E"=c(1,18,4))
key <- data.frame("cols"=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                  "include"=c("no","no","yes","no","yes"),
                  "subtract"=c("na","A","B","C","D"),
                  "names"=c("na","G","H","I","J"))
```

desired output dataframe:

```
output <- data.frame("A"=c("orange","apple","banana"),
                     "B"=c(5,3,6),
                     "C"=c(7,12,4),
                     "D"=c(5,2,7),
                     "E"=c(1,18,4),
                     "H"=c(2,9,-2),
                     "J"=c(-4,16,-3))
```

The keys dataframe has a row for each column in the base dataframe and an "include" column that has to be set to "yes" for any calculation to be done. If it is set to yes, then I want to add a new column with a defined name that subtracts a given column.

For example, column "C" in the base dataframe is set to included so I want to create a new column called "H" that has values from column "C" minus values from column "B".

I thought I could do this with a loop but my attempts have not been successful and my searches have not found anything that helped (I'm a bit new). Any help would be much appreciated.

sessioninfo():
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```
k <- subset(key, include == "yes")
output <- cbind(base,setNames(base[k[["cols"]]]-base[k[["subtract"]]],k$names))
```

and we will get

```
> output
       A B  C D  E  H  J
1 orange 5  7 5  1  2 -4
2  apple 3 12 2 18  9 16
3 banana 6  4 7  4 -2 -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you?

```
output <- base

for(i in which(key[["include"]] == "yes")){
  key.row <- key[i, ]
  output[[key.row[["names"]]]] <- base[[key.row[["cols"]]]] - base[[key.row[["subtract"]]]]
}
```

Result:

```
> output
       A B  C D  E  H  J
1 orange 5  7 5  1  2 -4
2  apple 3 12 2 18  9 16
3 banana 6  4 7  4 -2 -3
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks very close but I don't get the same output as you though unfortunately. Mine changes columns B and D in place: ```
> output
       A B  C D  E
1 orange 2  7 -4  1
2  apple 9 12 16 18
3 banana -2  4 -3  4
```

Comment: Do you mean you tried this in a fresh R session without loading any new package, with the example data as given above, & still didn't get the same output? If so, can you include the console output of `sessionInfo()` in your question?

Comment: yes, I've just added that for you. I also tried the code on the online compiler: https://rdrr.io/snippets/    but got the same result

Comment: The actual calculation is working great but it's changing the column in place rather than creating a new column as you had in your example output

Comment: Ok I know why. Set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create the `key` data frame, otherwise the names are treated as factor levels rather than characters. (as of R 4.0.0, FALSE is the default behaviour. But your R version--and that of R snippets--is rather old in this regard, so the default is TRUE.)

Comment: excellent, thank you so much for helping - I've learnt a lot and this also works but I am guessing the other answer will be quicker without the loop so I marked that one.